# How can I convert a ratio to number given total quantity?

Tags: math, algebra

Dealing with `put/call ratio` Is there a formula to convert a ratio `0.46` with a quantity of `978,551` to it's two sections? I know those two numbers are `670,053` and `308,498` but can not for the life of me seem to find any answer through Google.

Didn't know where to post this in the network.

Thanks,
Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let x = total quantity ( here 978,551)

let y = ratio ( here 0.46)

first quantity = (x*y)/(1+y)

second quantity = (x)/(1+y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let first quantity a and second be b. We know total number say x and ratio say y. By maths, a+b=x and a/b=y. From second equation a=by. Putting it in first one, b(1+y)=x, `b=x/(1+y)` and a=by, `a=xy/(1+y)`

Finally, first number= total/(1+ratio)
Second number=total*ratio/(1+ratio)